# Trying to install tensorflow package on raspi 3B+ gives an error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to install tensorflow on my raspberry pi, but when I try entering

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

into the terminal, it returns:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable  
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple  
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)  
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I've tried updating pip and python, as well as installing using [this](https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin/#usage:) tutorial, but it gives the same error when I try pip3 install tensorflow. I've also tried using a virtual environment, but it also gives the same error.

How do I install tensorflow?

Comment: can someone pls help T-T

Comment: Did you try to follow [this part](https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin/#usage) from the link you have provided, i.e. installing from a whl file? Which error did you get then

Comment: @Zevzzz Python 3.10? Tensorflow is not yet ready for Python 3.10. Downgrade to Python 3.9.

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes, I did, and it all installed until the "sudo pip3 uninstall tensorflow" part, where it said tensorflow is not installed.

Comment: @phd How do I downgrade?

Comment: Sorry, but of a beginner haha

Comment: Hi ! Did you check with "sudo -H pip3 install tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-none-linux_aarch64.whl" instead of "sudo pip3 tensorflow" after this command "$ ./tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-none-linux_aarch64_numpy1221_download.sh".

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Thanks for the reply! Yes, I did, and it returns: "WARNING: Requirement 'tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-none-linux_aarch32.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
ERROR: tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-none-linux_aarch32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."